# Table dynamic loading SAPUI5 / UI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

I want to display a huge set of data in a SAPUI5-Table component. I used to implement these datatables with dynamically loading, which means that the table initially loaded ~50 records. After the user scrolled down far enough, the next set of 50 records were loaded into the table. This way it was possible for me to display a table of more than 160.000 entries without any performance issues.

Now I need to do the same with SAPUI5-Table. I already implemented the server side, the OData service is ready to use. I already implemented the clientside but without that dynamic loading. The page always tries to load all records out of the database.

How can i achieve this? Is there any premade way to implement this? I know that the OData service can be called with various parameters which specify the dataset it will deliver, but i dont know how to make the table to these calls while scrolling?

Comment: Did you try the sap.ui.table.Table or just the sap.m.Table?

Comment: If you´re using `sap.m.Table` you can take a look at the `growing` properties [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Table/properties). Using `sap.ui.table.Table` the `threshold` property should be the right thing described [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Table.html#getThreshold). Both of them work fine bound to an [OData Model](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html).

Comment: about the parameters to call the odata service: you might add some filters (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169248(v=nav.71).aspx) to your oData-URL-Call. If I would have to implement this, I would use Paginator of Class sap.ui.table.Table and a hook "when clicking the next paginator page" I rebind the model only showing the current data set -> so your model only contains the current amount of data visible in one paginator page... your frontend stays at good performance (instead of pushing more and more data over time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, a table bound to an [OData Model](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html) does the most of it for you.

If you´re using `sap.m.Table` you can take a look at the `growing` properties [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Table/properties).

An example on how to use paging with a `sap.m.Table` can be found in the [Explored app](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListGrowing/preview) in the `List` section.

Using `sap.ui.table.Table` the `threshold` property controls the fetch size and is described [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Table.html#getThreshold). Additionally you can choose a `navigationMode`. It can be a Paginator as well as a Scrollbar.

A very simple example for `sap.ui.table.Table` looks like this:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("<yourURL>", true);
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
          columns : [], //set up columns as usual
          threshold : 50 //your fetch size here
});
oTable.setModel(oModel).bindRows("/<yourEntity>");
```