# OpenUI5; load data chunk wise into table

Tags: javascript, sapui5

*Yesterday I have asked the same question and got only one answer (which I tryed, see below). I'm not sure why it got downvoted. I have deleted it and am not trying again, trying to be clearer, and stating what I have tryed until now.*

I have a lot of data I want to display in an OpenUI5 applicatinon using `sap.ui.commons` and `sap.ui.table` libraries. As a backend server I use CherryPy which provides me the data (JSON) read from a SQLite databse. The backend is implemented in that way that the calling application provides an `offset` and and the number of rows it wants, beginning at that offset. I have already done so with another framework (w2ui).

This logic I need to reimplement with OpenUI5. What I have tryed so far:

- Unfortunatly `sap.ui.table.Table` does not provide a event that is fired when the user scrolled to the end of the current table data. Else I simply could request more data into the Model (currently it's `sap.ui.data.json.JSONMoel`) from the server. I don't know whether it is possible to create such an event myself.
- Pagination does have events, when the page was changed and which I could use to request further data. But the the controls at the bottom (arrows, page numbers) are only displayed for the current data. So if I load as many rows as one page could hold, a arrow button for the next page is not displayed. If I load data for two pages, it shows page numbers 1, 2 and arrows. But the `next page` arrow on page 2 is disabled, since there is no data for page 3. It also would add a new page number everytime data was added. One does never know how many pages there actually are as long as not all data was fetched.
- The third option I read [in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532238/table-dynamic-loading-sapui5-ui5). Here I am not quite sure if this is what I want. Although the question poster has exaclty the same problem as I do. Using `ODataModel`, if I understand it correctly, it still does load all the data from the backend but only renders the data that is visible for the user. I'm not quite sure how I would use that as I need. I don't know how it would automatically tell me the offset and number of rows. It is bound to the table model.

So my question would be which modules allow me to implement server communication as described.

**EDIT**

As for option 3, according to the comments I am doing it wrong. After creating a table

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table("table", {
    visibleRowCountMode: sap.ui.table.VisibleRowCountMode.Auto,
    threshold: 50,
    toolbar: oTableToolbar
});
```

I bind the table data model as follows

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("get_table_data_oui5", true);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "TableModel");
oTable.setModel(oModel);
oTable.bindRows("TableModel>/");
```

The function `get_table_data_oui5` exposed by CherryPy is called and the only parameter it receives is a string `$metadata` (except when I add own parameter). It does not receive `$top` and `$skip` and no values to them.

**EDIT 2**
These are the function calls I can see within Firefox and Chromium. Nothing except the string `$metadata` is transfered. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here but I don't know hat. If I have read correctly all I have to do is bind the model to the table.

Firefox:
[image: Output from Firefox]

Chromium:
[image: Output from Chromium]

Comment: you are wrong with the option 3, ODataModel will take care of the calls to be made with $top , $skip values.. You CherrPy should be able to handle these.. Basically what i meant to say was that, it will not load all the data.. It will load based on the threshold of the table you mention

Comment: @SunilBN I've edited my question. Maybe you can take a look at it.

Comment: I have never worked on CheeryPy, nevertheless, what do see in the network calls of browser?

Comment: @SunilBN I have edited my post. Thank you.

Comment: metadata is not valid, for odatamodel get method, first it will fetch metadata then the real GET call. There is some problem with metadata itself as per screenshot

Comment: @SunilBN my CherryPy server does not return any data on the first $metadata call. I don't know what kind of metadata it should return. I actually expected only the web application to give me metadata (meaning the offset and number of rows to return by the server). The OpenUI5 documentation is not very clear on that.